# Trying to parse xml throws FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am new to Python and all I am doing is parsing a simple XML string. But when I do that, it says 'No such file or directory' at Et.parse. I also tried saying `Et.parse(Et.fromstring(xmlfile))` but still that leads to a slightly different exception.

[image: xml parse error]

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    
    
thisDict={}
    
def parseXML(xmlfile):
    tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
    root=tree.getroot()
    for package in root.findall('package'):
    if package is None:
        continue
    if 'id' in package.attrib:
       thisDict['package']=package.get('id')
    if 'version' in package.attrib:
       thisDict['version']=package.get('version')

    for x, y in thisDict.items():
    print(x, y)


xmlstr=f'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
<package id="Castle.Core" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="Moq" version="4.18.4" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.3" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="xunit" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="xunit.abstractions" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="xunit.analyzers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="xunit.assert" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="xunit.core" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="xunit.extensibility.core" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="xunit.extensibility.execution" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="xunit.runner.visualstudio" version="2.4.5" targetFramework="net481" developmentDependency="true" />
</packages>'''

    
parseXML(xmlstr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the xml is a string you should use `ET.fromstring`.

For me this worked, but it means that you should adjust your code to not read the file:

```py
xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Moq" version="4.18.4" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.3" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="xunit" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="xunit.abstractions" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="xunit.analyzers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="xunit.assert" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="xunit.core" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.core" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.execution" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="xunit.runner.visualstudio" version="2.4.5" targetFramework="net481" developmentDependency="true" />
</packages>'''
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
tree.findall('package')
```

If you want to use your function you could use the`io` package:

```py
import io

def parseXML(xmlfile):
    tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
    root=tree.getroot()
    thisDict = {}
    for package in root.findall('package'):
        if package is None:
            continue
        if 'id' in package.attrib:
            thisDict['package']=package.get('id')
        if 'version' in package.attrib:
            thisDict['version']=package.get('version')

    for x, y in thisDict.items():
        print(x, y)

parseXML(io.StringIO(xml))
```

*note that I added `thisDict = {}` to your function. But it probably does not what you want, since the `'package'` key is overwritten every time a new package is found.*

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes that's true. I will figure out how to use the dictionary in python. It just retains one element like you said as the key is overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```py
root = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
```

As per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

The reason is that when you use `tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)` it searches for a file not a string

Answer (score 1):

**Import this data by reading from a file:**

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

**Or directly from a string:**

```py
root = ET.fromstring(country_data_as_string)
```

You should just use this:

```py
def parseXML(xmlfile):
    root = ET.fromstring(xmlfile)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

xmlstr=f'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
<package id="Castle.Core" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="Moq" version="4.18.4" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.3" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="xunit" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="xunit.abstractions" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="xunit.analyzers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="xunit.assert" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="xunit.core" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="xunit.extensibility.core" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="xunit.extensibility.execution" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net481" />
<package id="xunit.runner.visualstudio" version="2.4.5" targetFramework="net481" developmentDependency="true" />
</packages>'''

df = pd.read_xml(xmlstr, xpath = './/*')
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
                                    id version targetFramework developmentDependency
                           Castle.Core   5.1.1          net481                  None
                                   Moq  4.18.4          net481                  None
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe   4.5.3          net481                  None
     System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions   4.5.4          net481                  None
                                 xunit   2.4.2          net481                  None
                    xunit.abstractions   2.0.3          net481                  None
                       xunit.analyzers   1.0.0          net481                  None
                          xunit.assert   2.4.2          net481                  None
                            xunit.core   2.4.2          net481                  None
              xunit.extensibility.core   2.4.2          net481                  None
         xunit.extensibility.execution   2.4.2          net481                  None
             xunit.runner.visualstudio   2.4.5          net481                  true
```

Pandas have also a dataframe to dict():

```
d = df.to_dict('records')
print(d)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 'Castle.Core', 'version': '5.1.1', 'targetFramework': 'net481', 'developmentDependency': None}, {'id': 'Moq', 'version': '4.18.4', 'targetFramework': 'net481', 'developmentDependency': None}, {'id': 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe', 'version': '4.5.3', 'targetFramework': 'net481', 'developmentDependency': None}, {'id': 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions', 'version': '4.5.4', 'targetFramework': 'net481', 'developmentDependency': None}, {'id': 'xunit', 'version': '2.4.2', 'targetFramework': 'net481', 'developmentDependency': None}, {'id': 'xunit.abstractions', 'version': '2.0.3', 'targetFramework': 'net481', 'developmentDependency': None}, {'id': 'xunit.analyzers', 'version': '1.0.0', 'targetFramework': 'net481', 'developmentDependency': None}, {'id': 'xunit.assert', 'version': '2.4.2', 'targetFramework': 'net481', 'developmentDependency': None}, {'id': 'xunit.core', 'version': '2.4.2', 'targetFramework': 'net481', 'developmentDependency': None}, {'id': 'xunit.extensibility.core', 'version': '2.4.2', 'targetFramework': 'net481', 'developmentDependency': None}, {'id': 'xunit.extensibility.execution', 'version': '2.4.2', 'targetFramework': 'net481', 'developmentDependency': None}, {'id': 'xunit.runner.visualstudio', 'version': '2.4.5', 'targetFramework': 'net481', 'developmentDependency': 'true'}]
```